# SSL certificate for HTTPS website running tomcat as non-root user on centos

Tags: tomcat, centos, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to setup SSL certificate for HTTPS website (on centos 6.2) running tomcat server (6 or 7) as non-root account (/home/user/tomcat)?

Previously, I has this working on ubuntu but after switching to centos I was unable to get it working. So, I am wondering if this is due to centos' security features and in this case I can simply switch back to ubuntu.

Does anyone has experience with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Belongs on either serverfault or webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by following instructions from
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, for sure you can run SSL on port 8443.   As for running on ports 1024 or lower, in this case 443, I am unsure about the priviledges of a non-admin user on a CentOS system.